# Apache difference between VirtualHost with ip and without

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

In some apache file (site-enabled) you can see :

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/example1
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Another :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/example1
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

What's the difference between this two ligne :

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Usually i always use : `*:80` for the VirtualHost. But one of my friend on is server need to put the IP of the server. The `*:80` doesn't work.

Do you know why ? Did it's a special config ?
There is a way to know when we need to put the ip or not ?

Answer (score 2):

`<VirtualHost *:80>` Will serve the page to all requests on port 80

`<VirtualHost <IP>:80>` Will only serve requests that are sent to IP address specified. Can be useful if your web server has more than 1 IP address and you want to serve a specific page for each address.  This can take precedence over `*:80` depending on your configuration, check the output of `apachectl -S` to see what's attached where.

In most cases, `<VirtualHost *:80>` is a sensible value and your host will be able to serve pages even if the IP address might change in the future.

Comment: So if the `*:80` doesn't work on his server it's because he have more than 1 ip ? There is a way to know when we need to put the ip or not ?

Comment: The only way it might not work is if there are multiple VirtualHost entries. `*:80` should serve the page, no matter for wich address the request was sent. Check the apache logs for anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: There is a way to know of i need to put the ip or not ? Did the file port.conf give an advice ?

Comment: If *:80 does not work, is it possible the server's host-based firewall (iptables) is blocking incoming http requests?